# Adding a SDL_image in Codeblocks 20.03

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl-image

I am using CodeBlocks 20.03 and I want to use SDL_Image library to load JPEG, JPG and other image formats in my program. For that reason, I installed SDL_2.0.14 from the sdl website as a development library but not the runtime one. Now I copied all the .dll files into the MinGW bin folder and .lib files into the lib folder and again the SDL_image.h header file into SDL2 folder under the CodeBlocks compiler MinGW include folder.
Furthermore, I added the following lines in the linker library line through Settings->Compiler->Linker settings:-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
I am sorry to be unable to post any photos for not having 10 reputations.
And now I am trying to compile the following code in my SDL2 project:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"

int main()
{
    std::string path{"E:/C++ Project/Project/hrithik.jpg"};
    IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    IMG_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

But the wondering part is that my code doesn't compile, showing an error on the `IMG_Load(..)` line but, not in `SDL2/SDL_image.h` line.
I am using 64 bit Windows but 32 bit MinGW and SDL. I want to load png file format but without this function, it is not possible. Again, if I create any object of `enum IMG_InitFlags`, present in that header file the code works and compiles. I checked the header file definition and saw that my parameters were all correct.

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: I edited and made it E:/.. @Lutz Lehmann But I saw the same error and it is showing the same compile error. The interesting fact is when I use any enum from the SDL2_image.h header file, there is no error. The CodeBlocks IDE doesn't show the error statement. Just a compile error is indicated putting a red mark on the code line. Again, I revisited every installment step of adding SDL extensions in CodeBlocks but found none to work. Since the enum works, it means that the body of the function is absent.

Comment: This might be something like described in [this tutorial](https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/loading-images-in-sdl2-with-sdl_image/) *"Then, we initialise `SDL_image` by calling `IMG_Init()` right after the call to `SDL_Init()`"*. Note the flag variable containing bits for the image formats you want to use. It might be that as the workspace is not initialized, `SDL_image` refuses to do anything.

Comment: Or perhaps not, see https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_11.html. But try to get the error message of the initialization using `IMG_GetError()`, see [this carefully composed example](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats/index2.php).

Comment: And indeed, do you have a `SDL2` subdirectory in the project path that contains `SDL_image.h` (and is that the correct version)? Use the `< >` delimiters for headers that are to be found in the system and include paths.

Comment: I ran IMG_GetError() but need to comment out the IMG_Load line @Lutz Lehmann. The output was: Process returned 1878280864 (0x6FF44AA0) I have no idea about the flag variable you said in the 'this tutorial' comment, but the link was for Visual Studio where I am running Code Blocks 20.03. By the way thanks for the links